# File cannot be opened for embedding

Tags: movie15

What could be the reason for the below error ?

```
("E:/U3D-2-PDF\SDM 3d network.out")
("E:/U3D-2-PDF\SDM 3d network.out")

! Package movie15 Error: File `work.u3d' cannot be opened for embedding.
(movie15)                Did you forget to set option `url' or `inline=false'? 
.

See the movie15 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 ]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{work.u3d}
```

Comment: First of all: Your issue is unrelated to TeXworks. The problem is caused by the movie15 package. Probably your file is corrupted or not at the right place. As far as I can tell without seeing the document it has to be in the same directory as the TeX file.

Comment: Not sure what is bothering movie15 in the file name but if I use long name (ex: do some work.u3d) that causes the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not want to disclose the file name so I truncated it when I posted here
Turns out that movie15 was not OK with the name of the file (two words) As soon as I renamed the files and change the tex file used to generate the PDF eveyrhing worked